# Suitable test for one group sample(if values under 0)

Tags: r, math, statistics

I did some regressions/paired t tests on my sample I now want to test for my final hypothesis where I want to see if a single group of 50 observations is significantly under 0(not mean) so x<0 and if it is significant by how much as in an average of all the negative values which kind of te

Comment: Please provide reproducible codes so we can better understand the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about statistical tests and not a programming problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.